# Passing Dynamic values for Currency values in Ajax PhP Code

Tags: php, ajax

I am testing the following simple shopping cart from:

[Demo Site](http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/standalone-demo/)

On page load it can be seen in firebug that:

```
GET http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/standalone-demo/jcart/config-loader.php?ajax=true
```

(config-loader.php is being called). In json output it can be seen that currencyCode is USD. The config-loader.php includes config.php which contains a variable:

```
 $config['currencyCode'] = '';
```

and in config-loader.php:

```
 // Use default values for any settings that have been left empty
if (!$config['currencyCode']) $config['currencyCode'] = 'USD';
```

So if currency is set blank in config.php the default value is set to "USD".

If i hard code $config['currencyCode'] = 'GBP' in config.php the shopping cart works correctly displaying all values as GBP.

I have a currency conversion code in my shopping page with the variable $curr whose value is  set with currency codes like AUD,GBP etc...for different users. A user can choose his currency and converted value is displaying in cart.

My shopping page: sample

```
 <?php
 $curr = "GBP";
 include_once('jcart/jcart.php');
?>

 <form method="post" action="" class="jcart">
 <fieldset>
 <input type="hidden" name="jcartToken" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['jcartToken'];?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="my-item-id" value="<?php echo $pid ; ?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="my-item-name" value="<?php echo $product['product_name']; ?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="my-item-price" value="<?php echo $sp ; ?>" />
 <input type="image" src="AddtoCart.gif" alt="Add to Cart"  value="add to cart" />  
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I need to set the value of currencyCode in config.php to the value in my shopping page when user clicks add to cart Button and on page load while calling config-loader.php ...

How is it possible...

**Update:**

resolved it by passing a **new currency var** to the ajax code

```
var config = (function() {
        var config = null;
        $.ajax({
            url: path + '/config-loader.php' + '?curr=' + currency,
            data: {
                "ajax": "true"
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
```

Comment: You asked this question earlier, and the response was to store the value in a database and manage it that way, instead of managing the value in a file. Is there any reason you are not choosing to do that?

Comment: @Alex I tried using database and added session value and currency to Db. But I am unable to pass it to config.php currency value. Getting NULL values. Values are obtained in shopping cart by Ajax calls

Comment: Do you know how to pass values to a php script via ajax?

Comment: @Alex The relevant code is: var config = (function() {
   var config = null;
   $.ajax({
    url: path + '/config-loader.php',
    data: {
     "ajax": "true"
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(response) {
     config = response;
    },
    error: function() {
     alert('Ajax error: Edit the path in jcart.js to fix.');
    }
   });
   return config;
  }());   If i was able to pass value to /config-lodaer.php?curr=my currency then that would be fine...I am a newbie and did not do how to do that ???

Comment: I tried using sessions...but currencyCode will get refreshed only on page load..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if (!isset($config['currencyCode']) && !empty($config['currencyCode']))   
    $config['currencyCode'] = 'USD';
```

Comment: What are you answering is totally unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that a User can select a currency from a drop down list, which might look like this:

```
<select id="currency">
  <option>GBP</option>
  <option>USD</option>
  <option>EUR</option>
</select>
```

Then, you would like to pass whichever option they selected, to a PHP script. So, first, in javascript, just before your AJAX call:

```
// get the selected option
var currencyChosen = $('#currency').find(":selected").text();

// now pass it to the script
var config = $.ajax({ 
    url: path + '/config-loader.php', 
    data: { "ajax": "true", "currencyCode" : currencyChosen }
    ...
})
```

Would send a variable called `currencyCode` to the PHP script. It would be accessed in the script with `$code = $_GET['currencyCode'];`.